# How to check privileges in JWT using Claims in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, claims-based-identity

I have a question about Claims, JWT, and ASP.Net Core. Again... (Greetings Chris). So...

I have my JWT with **Claim**:

```
"Authorization": "CanEditUnit,CanBrowseUnit,CanCreateUnit,CanDeleteUnit,CanSeeUnitDetails,CanBrowseRole,CanEditRole,CanCreateRole,CanDeleteRole,CanSeeRoleDetails,CanBrowseUser,CanSeeUserDetails,CanDeleteUser,CanEditUser,CanRegisterNewUser"
```

etc.

This **Claim** has all privileges, that user contains (for example: If the user has CanEditUnit in a database set to True, CanEditUnit is saved in **Authorization** Claim, but if something is set to False it simply doesn't appear in that Claim.

Then I want to check if user has that Privilages in Policies like that:

```
options.AddPolicy("CanEditUnit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Authorization", "CanEditUnit"));
```

But it probably checks if **Authorization** Claim is equal to **CanEditUnit**.

Is there a way to check policies with *Contains* instead of *Equal*? If not, what should I do them?

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireassertion?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in docs, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've suggested in your question, it looks like `RequireAssertion` has the ability to handle this for you. Here's an example:

```
policy.RequireAssertion(ctx =>
{
    var authorizationClaim = ctx.User.FindFirstValue("Authorization");

    if (authorizationClaim == null)
        return false;

    return authorizationClaim.Split(",").Contains("CanEditUnit");
});
```

This simply looks for an `Authorization` claim and, if it exists, splits it by `,` and checks for the existence of a `CanEditUnit` value.

If you want something a little more reusable, you can create a custom `AssertionRequirement` class of your own. Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
public class CustomAssertionRequirement : AssertionRequirement
{
    public CustomAssertionRequirement(string requiredValue)
        : base(ctx => HandleRequirement(ctx, requiredValue)) { }

    private static bool HandleRequirement(AuthorizationHandlerContext ctx, string requiredValue)
    {
        var authorizationClaim = ctx.User.FindFirstValue("Authorization");

        if (authorizationClaim == null)
            return false;

        return authorizationClaim.Split(",").Contains(requiredValue);
    }
}
```

In order to use this new class, you can add it as a requirement to the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` (instead of using `RequireAssertion`), like so:

```
policy.AddRequirements(new CustomAssertionRequirement("CanEditUnit"));
```